# ANOVA Feature Selection in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-selection, anova

```
data=pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharmaroshan/Online-Shoppers-Purchasing- Intention/master/online_shoppers_intention.csv")
```

I'm trying to perform feature selection based on ANOVA (Categorical vs Numerical variable).

dependent variable: Revenue 
independent variable: Administrative,Administrative_Duration

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from   statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from   statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm
model = ols('Revenue ~ Informational',data = data).fit()
anova_table=anova_lm(model)
```

But getting an following error,

[Value Error(Shape issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNYMR.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the column `Revenue` in data, because it is boolean.
In fact, if you convert from boolean to integer then it works:

```
data.Revenue = data.Revenue.astype(int)
```

Comment: OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) requires the dependent variable to be numeric! Logistic regression instead accepts also categorical variables. Could you please accept my answer? thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing me out, Just to confirm if we map/convert to int will the interpretation of the result for the ANOVA will be the same or it will analysed to numerical values on independent column(REVENUE).

Comment: @MooventhChiyan The conversion to Integer is just changing each `True` to 1 and `False` to 0. This will not affect the results of ANOVA.

Comment: Thanks that's all :) Perfect.

Comment: You are welcome! I would suggest to try also Logistic regression. This because your dependent variable (Revenue) is binary, and Logistic regression is usually applied in these situations. Bye!